# How to properly import blessed?

Tags: python, blessed

I've just started studying python and I really liked blessed looked like and wanted to give it a try.

I installed it using `pip install blessed` on the console and then I copied the following code from their site:

```
import os
import sys

print('Test run')

try:
    from blessed import Terminal
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print('Could find the import :(')
```

After running the code, I receive the 'ModuleNotFoundError' exception.

How do I proper install blessed to avoid this error?

-- Edit

After some research turns out that `py -m pip install blessed` solved my problem.

Even though it is working now, what is the difference between using `py -m pip install blessed` and `pip install blessed`, which is what I used before?

Comment: Please, provide more information of the problem you are struggling with. Add the exception, traceback and other things you might think will help us solve the problem.

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "just doesn't work" mean? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your edit suggests that your system's `pip` command runs pip for a different interpreter than the one you get by default when you run `py` (which is probably what you were using to run your script too). Each interpreter installed on your system will have its own set of installed modules, and it's own `pip` program to manage them. One interpreter usually can't use the modules installed for a different interpreter.